# Behavioral difference between Gradient Desent and Hill Climbing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, gradient-descent, hill-climbing

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two algorithms and how they differ in solving a problem. I have looked at the algorithms and the internals of them. It would be good to hear from others who already experienced with them. Specially, I would like to know how they would behave differently on the same problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Difference

The main `difference` between the two is the `direction` in which they move to reach the local minima (or maxima).

- In **`Hill Climbing`** we move **only** `one element` of the `vector space`, we then calculate the value of function and replace it if the value improves. we keep on changing one element of the vector till we can't move in a direction such that position improves. In `3D sapce` the move can be visualised as moving in any one of the `axial direction` along `x,y or z axis`.
- In **`Gradient Descent`** we take steps in the direction of `negative gradient` of current point to reach the point of `minima` (positive in case of maxima). For eg, in `3D Space` the direction `need not` to be an `axial direction`.

Comment: If the function is continuous and differentiable shall we expect a different result? Or would hill climbing be more adapted to a search space which arguments are discrete?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to radbrawler's answer, they are however similar in the greedy approach that both use to find local minima/maxima. I may consider Gradient descent as the continuous version of the discrete Hill climbing technique.

Comment: No, gradient ascent/descent cannot be considered a continuous analog of discrete Hill climbing. An expectation-maximization algorithm can such as Baum-Welch for Hidden Markov Models. Hill climbing will converge to the nearest local maxima whereas gradient ascent will not necessarily.